# Gantt chartt not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, xml-parsing

I'm working on an mvc .net application and I'm using jsgantt for displaying Gantt chart. I used an xml file for extracting data from database. The problem is that when I use Chrome as a navigator it doesn't display the chart however with Firefox and IE it works normally

Here is the code for reading xml files (default code)

```
JSGantt.parseXML = function(ThisFile,pGanttVar){
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('Chrome') > -1;   // Is this Chrome 

    try { //Internet Explorer  
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        }
    catch(e) {
        try { //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, Chrome etc. 
            if (is_chrome==false) {  xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null); }
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert(e.message);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (is_chrome==false) {     // can't use xmlDoc.load in chrome at the moment
        xmlDoc.async=false;
        xmlDoc.load(ThisFile);      // we can use  loadxml
        JSGantt.AddXMLTask(pGanttVar)
        xmlDoc=null;            // a little tidying
        Task = null;
    }
    else {
        JSGantt.ChromeLoadXML(ThisFile,pGanttVar);  
        ta=null;    // a little tidying 
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that? Regards

Comment: There is an explicit condition in there to do nothing if the browser is Chrome. Why, you'd have to ask the author of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;   // Is this Chrome 
    var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1;   // Is this safari 
    var is_mozila = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;   // Is this mozila 
    var is_Opera = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('opera') > -1;   // Is this opera 

if(is_safari==true)
{var is_chrome= is_safari;}
else if(is_mozila==true)
{var is_chrome= is_mozila;}
else if(is_Opera==true)
{var is_chrome= is_Opera;}


try { //Internet Explorer   
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

    }
catch(e)
  {
    try { 

        //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, Chrome etc. 
        if (is_chrome==false) { xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null); }
        //if (is_safari==false) { xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null); }
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert(e.message);
        return;
    }       
}

if (is_chrome==false) {     // can't use xmlDoc.load in chrome at the moment
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.load(ThisFile);      // we can use  loadxml
    JSGantt.AddXMLTask(pGanttVar);
    xmlDoc=null;            // a little tidying
    Task = null;
}
else {
    JSGantt.loadXML(ThisFile,pGanttVar; 
    ta=null;    // a little tidying 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check [jsGanttImproved](https://github.com/jsGanttImproved/jsgantt-improved), it works with Chrome and all the major browsers. Also, it doesn't require any additional libraries and it is FREE.